# Running time complexity of a code fragment

Tags: algorithm, analysis

Here is the fragment:

```
sum1=0;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
      for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        sum1++
sum2=0
    for(k=1;k<=n;k*=2)
      for(j=1;j<=k;j++)
        sum2++
```

Below is the answer:

2 assignment statements – O(1) each
1st nested loop – O(n2)
2nd nested loop – O(n)
Running time complexity of code fragment = O(1) + O(n^2) + O(1) + O(n) = O(n2)

But here is how I worked it out:

2 assignments:- O(1).
First nested loop: O(n*n)=O(n^2)
    Second nested loop:

Outer loop runs n times..
Now the inner loop will be executed (1+2+3+.....+(n-1)+n) times
which gives n(n+1)/2 =O(n^2)

Total running time = O(n^2)+O(n^2)+O(1)=O(n^2)

And yes I've done some research and I came across the following:

In a loop if an index jumps by an increasing amount in each iteration the sequence has complexity log n.

In that case I suppose the second loop will have complexity (n-1)/2*logn...which will be equal to O(n*log n).

I'm really confused with the second loop whether it should be O(n)..O(n^2) or O(nlogn)..

HELP PLEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you k increased double each time .  your calculation is  not correct. It should be (1+2+4+....n/2+n)

```
     for(k=1;k<=n;k*=2)
```

So, O(nlogn) is right.